# Lambda and Expression.Call for an extension method

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, extension-methods, expression-trees

I need to implement an expression for a method like here:

```
var prop = Expression.Property(someItem, "Name"); 
var value = Expression.Constant(someConstant);

var contains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] {typeof(string)});
var expression = Expression.Call(prop, contains, value);
```

But for my extension method:

```
public static class StringEx
{
    public static bool Like(this string a, string b)
    {
        return a.ToLower().Contains(b.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, next code throws an ArgumentNullException for a parameter "method":

```
var like = typeof(string).GetMethod("Like", new[] {typeof(string)});
comparer = Expression.Call(prop, like, value);
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a non-generic static extension method with parameters using Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786153/how-to-call-a-non-generic-static-extension-method-with-parameters-using-reflecti)

Answer (score 18):

Try this

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public static class StringEx
{
    public static bool Like(this string a, string b)
    {
        return a.ToLower().Contains(b.ToLower());
    }
}

Person p = new Person(){Name = "Me"};
var prop = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(p), "Name");
var value = Expression.Constant("me");
var like = typeof(StringEx).GetMethod("Like", BindingFlags.Static
                        | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var comparer = Expression.Call(null, like, prop, value );

var vvv = (Func<bool>) Expression.Lambda(comparer).Compile();
bool isEquals = vvv.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this:

```
var like = typeof(StringEx).GetMethod("Like", new[] {typeof(string), typeof(string)});

comparer = Expression.Call(null, like, prop, value);
```

You can pass `prop` as first parameter and `value` as second parameter like above.

Maybe you will need to get a complete query before apply an extension method.

Comment: This makes sense and is exactly what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but you can only get an extension method from the static class using reflection. Extension methods are not truly added to the class, therefore can't be retrieved with `GetMethod`.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I need to call GetMethod this way: `typeof(StringEx).GetMethod("Like", new[] {typeof(string)});` but how I have to inject my parameters in Expression.Call?

Comment: See @Lonli-Lokli's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var like = typeof(StringEx).GetMethod("Like", new[] {typeof(string),typeof(string)});
```

ie. retrieve it from the extending type, not from the extended type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this throws an argument exception: Need null instance for static method, so I need some magic with BindingFlags.Static, but this is outside from my comprehension(

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get your extension method worked you must do like this:

```
string str = "some string";
str.Like("second string");
```